# Converting Char to Integer in Common Lisp

Tags: types, lisp, common-lisp

What is the proper way to convert the character `#\1` to the integer `1`?
I coerced a number into a list and got this:
`(#\1 #\2 #\3)`

and want to convert that into

```
(1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
CL-USER > (digit-char-p #\1)
1
```

`digit-char-p` returns

- the numeric value of the character, if it is a digit char
- `NIL` otherwise

Thus it is both:

- a predicate, since numbers are *true*
- a conversion function

Comment: Got to love the duality of this as it seems it's also a predicate :)

Comment: @Sylwester The `-p` on the end informs you this is a predicate before you know anything else about it.

Comment: @Sylwester It is _also_ a predicate, since it returns either a number or `NIL` if the number is not defined within it's optional radix argument.

Answer (score -2):

A little love for the low-tech solution?

```
(parse-integer (string #\1))
```

Less efficient but still worth mentioning.

Comment: `(- (char-int #\1) (char-int #\0))`